# what are the benefits of a factorial number system?

Tags: number-theory, number-systems

After reading an article about [factorial number system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system). It tells that you can present any number in a factorial system and in if you have a number $a_{n-1}...a_2a_1a_0$ in factorial number system, you can transform it to decimal as $\sum_{i=0}^{n}i!\cdot a_i$.

Nonetheless I found it really cool, I can not find a lot of applications of such a system beyond:

- finding n-th lexicographical permutation (which is highlighted in the wiki)
- big numbers can be represented with smaller number of digits (number higher than 25!)

Are there other applications of this number system?

Comment: @SimonS I agree with you. You can not add/subtract/multiply/divide easily.  The only real advantage is to find n-th ordered permutations. But I hope that some of smart mathematicians would be able to show me some cool applications.

Comment: Actually addition and subtraction should not be much more difficult than decimal or hexadecimal addition or subtraction.  However, considering the difficulty multiplying and dividing constant polynomials it would seem to require significantly more computational power.  I don't think it will convert easily into binary/ hexadecimal either.  For computer arithmetic, this would require special libraries and in most cases significantly reduce the effectiveness of special purpose math processors built into modern computers.  For similar reasons binary coded decimals(BCD) are rarely used anymore.

Comment: All that being said potential applications are A. finding prime numbers, B. cryptography, which uses large prime numbers and C. possibly number theory.

Comment: @nickalh is it possible to explain how can I find prime numbers with factorial number system?

Comment: I was only thinking of storing large numbers in your factorial system.  The largest known prime has 17 million digits.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Largest_known_prime_number#The_ten_largest_known_prime_numbers    On a practical level, the difficulty with division or multiplication of your form, very similar to high degree polynomials, probably far outweighs the advantage gained from smaller storage.  Possibly applications in number theory because it primarily deals with integers.  That could be a long shot also.